# How to required selection option user checked radio button Yes and removed required if checked on No In jQuery or Javascript before submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to validate this before submitting kindly help me.

[image]

MY HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">VAT Register</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="icheck-inline">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="vat_register" id="vatRegYes" class="icheck">
          Yes </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" value="No" name="vat_register" id="vatRegNo" checked class="icheck">
          No </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">VAT Number</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="vat_number"  class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">VAT Quarters</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="vat_quarters" id="vatQuar" class="form-control select2me">
      <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
      <option value="Jan - April - July - October" >Jan - April - July - October</option>
      <option value="Feb - May - August - November" >Feb - May - August - November</option>
      <option value="March - June - September - December" >March - June - September - December</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#vatRegYes').click(function(){

                if($(this).prop("checked") == true){

                    //alert("Checkbox is checked.");
                    $('#vatQuar').attr("required", "true");

                }

                else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){

                    //alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
                    $('#vatQuar').removeAttr('required');​​​​​

                }

            });

        });

    </script>
```

This is working fine but only for Yes mean when i checked yes Vat Quarters set as required but when i again checked not Vat Quarters Still remain required. i only want required when yes is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `required` is a property, You should use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), I would recommend to use `change` event instead of `click` for `radio` group and also the code can be reduced to following.

A good read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('[name="vat_register"]').change(function() {
     $('#vatQuar').prop("required", $('#vatRegYes').prop("checked"));
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icheck-inline">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="vat_register" id="vatRegYes" class="icheck">Yes</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="No" name="vat_register" id="vatRegNo" checked class="icheck">No</label>
</div>
<div>
  <select name="vat_quarters" id="vatQuar" class="form-control select2me">
    <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
    <option value="Jan - April - July - October">Jan - April - July - October</option>
    <option value="Feb - May - August - November">Feb - May - August - November</option>
    <option value="March - June - September - December">March - June - September - December</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not working for me can you please show me demo ?

Comment: @MuddasirAbbas, Updated answer you can inspect element

Answer (score 0):

`required` is a boolean html attribute. So you must use `prop`.

```
if($(this).prop("checked") == true){

    //alert("Checkbox is checked.");
    $('#vatQuar').prop("required", "true");

}

else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){

    //alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    $('#vatQuar').prop('required', false);​​​​​

}
```

And you have to listen the `click` event on a parent of your two radios input.

Like this :

```
$('.input-group').click(function(){
    var value = $('#vatRegYes').prop('checked');

    if(value == true){

        //alert("Checkbox is checked.");
        $('#vatQuar').prop("required", "true");

    }

    else if(value == false){

        //alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
        $('#vatQuar').prop('required', false);​​​​​

    }
});
```

As suggested by Satpal; you can also use the `change` event. Both methods will works.